# Is it possible to take S3 snapshots of OpenEBS Jiva live volumes? If so, how?

Tags: amazon-s3, snapshot, openebs, kubernetes-pvc

How can I take S3 snapshot of OpenEBS jiva volume which is being accessed regularly? Is there any pause on volume while taking the snapshot? Do you have a way to do this one?